# Match as many words of a sentence as possible

Tags: java, regex, string, sentence

Ok I know a regex isn't the best thing to use but I believe it is the best thing besides writing a complete parser and grammar checking and everything.

I want to write a regex to match as many tokens as possible in a specific order and also write another regex to match as many tokens as possible in any order in a sentence.

For example, I wrote a regex for matching words in order such as:

`(?=.*?(I|need|your))(?=.*?(help|assistance|support|with|this|regex)).*?(?:\?)`

and it matches:

`I think I need your help?
I need your assistance with this regex?
I don't want your support.`

but the problem is that it only matches "I" and "help" in the first sentence.
In the second sentence, it only matches "I" and "assistance".

I'm trying to figure out how to get it to match as many of the keywords in order as possible so:

"I", "need", "help" for the first sentence.
"I", "need", "assistance", "with", "this", "regex" for the second sentence.

but at the same time I don't want it matching something like:

"need", "I", "with", "assistance" because it isn't in order.

Is there a way I can do this? I usually test my regexes with: http://regex101.com/ and using `g` as the flag but I cannot figure out how to write such a regex.

I was able to tokenize the sentence using `"\\b[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b"`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

First tokenize with your regex. Then you can check if it's a valid word with a definition with one of these apis https://www.google.com/#q=dictionary+api